# Softlayer API: Cannot cancel virtual machine

Tags: api, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Team,

I am having issues canceling a virtual machine via API/CLI.

```
slcli virtual cancel 27493017
```

> This action cannot be undone! Type "27493017" or press Enter to abort:
>   27493017 SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This
>   cancellation could not be processed please contact support.This
>   cancellation could not be processed. Please contact support. Unable to
>   create cancel ticket for virtual server.

```
slcli --version
slcli (SoftLayer Command-line), version 5.1.0
```

I can cancel through the UI

-Guy

Answer (score 0):

Something weird, I recommend to submit a ticket for further assistance. but I see the virtual: **27493017** is already deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   I submitted a ticket: https://control.softlayer.com/support/tickets/36373393

They told me to submit the stack overflow question.

I have already deleted this virtual machine with UI.  I still have this problem in general with all cancels. 

Thank you for helping.

Comment: I dont really have any answer from SL support.  They said someone on the Development team was going to take a look.  I am still having the issues and updated the Support ticket with a new host to try to delete.

Comment: Ok.. I answered my own question. It was permissions. I enabled 'Super User' permission set and am able to 'cancel' via api. I must say the error message was not encouraging. 'Contact Support', you would think it would return 'Access Denied'. You would think this case would have been a slam dunk.

Now I need to know the exact permission in the portal to allow my user to 'cancel' virtual machines. If I can get help here I can lower the permissions on SuperUser (dangerous).

Comment: You need the **Cancel Server** permission enabled, additionaly you need to have **View Virtual Server Details** for Vsi's or **View Hardware Details** for bms's. Also you must have access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times when you see that message it indicates that an existing transaction is on going for the VSI. Double check with the command `slcli --format=raw call-api Virtual_Guest getActiveTransaction --id=VIRTUAL_GUEST_ID`

Comment: I had attempted to cancel 27499277 with no luck. 

Please feel free to experiment with this host. 

guy$ slcli virtual cancel 27499277
This action cannot be undone! Type "27499277" or press Enter to abort: 27499277
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This cancellation could not be processed please contact support.This cancellation could not be processed. Please contact support. Unable to create cancel ticket for virtual server.

guy$ slcli --format=raw call-api Virtual_Guest getActiveTransaction --id=27499277
(This returned nothing)